# Double String Variable Name (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are other questions similar to this, but I feel as if they don't answer my question. I would basically like to make Dynamic Variable Names. Let me give you an example:

```
//Take the strings "new" and "variable" and make them into a variable.
"new" + "variable" = "Hello World";
//So technically the variable name is "newvariable" and has the value "Hello World"
```

So basically it takes two strings, and combines them into one variable name. How would I go about doing this?

*P.S. This is **NOT** to combine the values of variables, just the names*

Comment: Oh, I never found that post on SO, Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it into an array or object

```
var arr = {};
arr['new' + 'variable'] = 'Hello World';
```

then

```
alert(arr['newvariable']);
```

or

```
alert(arr.newvariable);
```

Comment: So, to access this variable do I just type in `window['newvariable']` each time?

Comment: Yes, but actually putting the variables into the `window` namespace isn't a good idea. Better create a new `vars[]` in that case, and then have `vars['newvariable']`.

Comment: yes, that's it. basically usnig the 'newvariable' as an array (or object) key

Comment: Thank You! :) That explains it much better.

Comment: Why create an empty array to attach an arbitrary property?  You can just use an object literal:  `var arr = {};`

Comment: So just to verify, something like this would be totally correct? `var dynamic["replyupvote" + String(replyid)] = false;`

Comment: @hildende I am very confused right now. I am using this `dynamic["replyupvote"+replyid]` to write my variables, and it does not seem to be working. Any idea why? Thank You! :) *P.S. if you would like to see my full code it is here: **http://pastebin.com/tpS4pPtf***

Comment: You're using an array the way you'd use an object. It works, but it makes little sense.